# How to disable a button when multiple items are selected in QTableView

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

I have a `QTableView` and a bunch of buttons for edit,add and delete functionalities. It is shown below-
[image]

I want the Add and Edit buttons to be disabled if multiple items from Table are selected. If single item is selected then it should be enabled. I know that multiple item selection can be detected by following code:
`TableView->selectionModel()->selectedRows();`. But how to disable buttons if more than 1 row is selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make slot connected to signal `void selectionChanged(const QItemSelection & selected, const QItemSelection & deselected)` (qt documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qitemselectionmodel.html#selectionChanged) of `QItemSelectionModel`, which you can determine as TableView->selectionModel(). Something like this:

```
void slotSelectionChanged(const QItemSelection & selected,
                          const QItemSelection & deselected)
{
    Q_UNUSED(deselected);
    QModelIndexList indexies = selected.indexes();
    QVector<int> rows;
    foreach(const QModelIndex& index, indexies)
    {
        int row = index.row();
        if(!rows.contains(row))
        {
            rows.append(row);
        }

        if(rows.count() > 1)
            break;
    }

    if(rows.count() > 1)
    {
        //set button enabled false
        button->setEnabled( false );
    }
    else
    {
        //set button enabled true
        button->setEnabled( true );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you detected the multiple item selection, try this:

```
button->setEnabled( false );
```

Comment: More likely something like button->setEnabled(TableView->selectionModel()->selectedRows().size() <= 1);  // to be called in a slot that is connected to the signal QItemSelectionModel::selectionChanged(const QItemSelection &selected, const QItemSelection &deselected)